# What was unique about Gevas and Antifras that Rebbi Akiva singled them out?

Tags: midrash, sefirat-ha-omer, masechet-yevamot

The [Gemara Yevamos (62b)](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.62b.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [Midrash Koheles Rabbah (11:6)](https://www.sefaria.org/Kohelet_Rabbah.11.6.1?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=bi&with=Yefeh%20To%27ar&lang2=en) single out two specific students who died out of the 12,000:

> וְרַבִּי עֲקִיבָא אוֹמֵר שְׁנֵים עָשָׂר אֲלָפִים תַּלְמִידִים הָיוּ לִי מִגְּבַת וְעַד אַנְטִיפְרַס וְכֻלָּן מֵתוּ בְּחַיַּי בֵּין פֶּסַח לַעֲצֶרֶת - Rebbi Akiva said, "I had 12,000 students, from Gevas until Antifras, who all died in my lifetime between Pesach and Shavuos."

What was unique about Gevas and Antifras that Rebbi Akiva singled them out? (Are they far apart, major metropolises, etc.)

Comment: Your first link translates it as " in an area of land that stretched from Gevat to Antipatris"

Comment: It should be noted that in most versions of this midrash, Rabbi Akiva does not mention it, but rather, it is told about Rabbi Akiva.

Comment: Those who theorize that this was coded language for the Bar Kochva Revolt say these sites are parts of the clue, e.g. *Gevat, east of present-day Haifa, was well-placed as a military centre to cover the northern Galil region ... Antipatris, in Roman times, stood at the junction of important highways leading to Jerusalem, Caesarea and Jaffa and is often mentioned as a military campsite* https://www.thejc.com/judaism/features/the-historical-disaster-the-rabbis-covered-up-1.33200

Comment: +1, In ancient parlance, mentioning two distant (in their view) geographic places meant "all over the world", like "מהודו ועד כוש" or "all over the country, like we say in modern Hebrew "from Gadera to Hadera" (because it rhymes, meaning all over Israel). It could also be possible that it was a single well-known governmental district, kind of "figure of speech".

Answer (score 4):

It is an area of land.

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.62b.9?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Yevamot.62b.9.1&lang2=bi) writes:

> מגבת עד אנטיפרס - [בין העיירות הללו היו כולם]:
>
> From Gevas until Antifras - i.e. all of them (that died were located) between these cities.

[Steinsaltz](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.62b.9?lang=bi&p2=Steinsaltz_on_Yevamot.62b.9&lang2=bi) adds:

> שמגבת עד אנטיפרס בארץ יהודה
>
> That were from Gevas until Antifras - In the land of Yehuda.

And the [Etz Yosef](https://www.sefaria.org/Kohelet_Rabbah.11.6.1?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=bi&p2=Etz_Yosef_on_Kohelet_Rabbah.11.6.1.7&lang2=bi) on the Midrash there writes quite clearly:

> שמות מקומות
>
> They are the names of places.

Comment: Thank you - is there something unique about the two cities?

Comment: I have to do a bit more research....

Comment: I don't understand - only those between the cities died, but there were more?

Answer (score 2):

These two cities (with some variance in spelling) are commonly used in Aggadah to designate the borders of the land of Yehudah; see, e.g. Sanhedrin 94b, as per Rashi and Steinsaltz (note the parallel to "from Dan to Be'er Sheva"):

> מה עשה נעץ חרב על פתח בית המדרש ואמר כל מי שאינו עוסק בתורה ידקר בחרב זו בדקו מדן ועד באר שבע ולא מצאו עם הארץ מגבת ועד אנטיפרס ולא מצאו תינוק ותינוקת איש ואשה שלא היו בקיאין בהלכות טומאה וטהרה

> What did Hezekiah do to ensure Torah study? He inserted a sword at the entrance of the study hall and said: Anyone who does not engage in Torah study shall be stabbed with this sword. As a result, they searched from Dan in the north to Beersheba in the south, and did not find an ignoramus. They searched from Gevat to Antipatris and did not find a male child, or a female child, or a man, or a woman who was not expert even in the complex halakhot of ritual purity and impurity.

Rashi ad loc.:

> ‏מגבת ועד אנטיפרס - מקומות שבסוף התחומים:

Steinsaltz ad loc:

> ‏ בדקו מגבת ועד אנטיפרס (שהן תחומי ארץ יהודה)

You can find their Wikipedia entries (and thus their approximate locations) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gvat) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipatris).